# Timers.ElapsedEventHandler function not firing

Tags: c#

```
static  System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    static string _ScheduledRunningTime ="6:00 AM";

    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        try
            {
            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(6000);
            _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
            _timer.Enabled = true;
            _timer.Start();
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
            //Displays and Logs Message
            _loggerDetails.LogMessage = ex.ToString();
            _writeLog.LogDetails(_loggerDetails.LogLevel_Error, _loggerDetails.LogMessage);
            }
        }

    static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
        string _CurrentTime=String.Format("{0:t}", DateTime.Now);
        if (_CurrentTime == _ScheduledRunningTime)
            {
            ExtractDataFromSharePoint();
            }
        }
```

This is my code and i am not able to identitfy that why timer_Elapsed Method is not firing and what wrong i am doing in this code.

Comment: Is it because you've tried that code in console application that terminated before timer fired? Your post does not provide enough information for better guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application is closing before the event is fired. Please use a Console.ReadKey() at the end of Main method or another sync.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your application stops almost immediately. That is because Console application are typically input/output applications that end as soon as there are no more Read or Write actions in your code.

Windows Forms and WPF have a messaging system that runs until you end your application.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick  for your answer. I just want to know that if i copy the same code in a windows service than it run or no?